# How to fastly select dataframe according to multi-columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I want to want to filter rows by multi-column values.

For example, given the following dataframes,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["Amy", "Amy", "Amy", "Bob", "Bob",],
                  "group":[1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                   "place":['a', 'a', "a", 'b', 'b'],
                    "y":[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
})

print(df)
```

`Original dataframe:`

```
name  group place  y
0  Amy      1     a  1
1  Amy      1     a  2
2  Amy      1     a  3
3  Bob      1     b  1
4  Bob      2     b  2
```

I want to select the samples that satisfy the columns combination [`name`, `group`, `place`] in `selectRow`.

`selectRow = [["Amy", 1, "a"], ["Amy", 2, "b"]]`

Then the `expected dataframe` is :

```
  name  group place  y
0  Amy      1     a  1
1  Amy      1     a  2
2  Amy      1     a  3
```

I have tried it and my method is not efficient and runs for a long time, especially when there are many samples in original dataframe.

`My Simple Method:`

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame({})
for item in (selectRow):
    print(item)
    tmp = df.loc[(df['name'] == item[0]) & (df['group'] == item[1]) &  (df['place'] == item[2])]
    newdf = newdf.append(tmp)
newdf = newdf.reset_index( drop = True)
newdf.tail()
print(newdf)
```

Hope for an efficient method to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `isin`:

```
print(df[df['name'].isin(list(zip(*selectRow))[0]) & df['group'].isin(list(zip(*selectRow))[1]) & df['place'].isin(list(zip(*selectRow))[2])])
```